# Advanced AutoCompleteTextView. Many-to-one map

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I want the autocomplete view to display multiple items for the same text item.

ie. with an input data, {{a,b,c,d}, {e,f,g,h}} the user could search and start typing in b, but only 1 item from a,b,c,d would be displayed in the autocomplete section.

How would I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found I could solve this problem by adding all the elements to the autocompletetextview like normal

However, for the items that had "aliases" I put them in as 1 item, separated by a separator character and a space. The space allowed the item to be selected using the normal functionality. Then I used a custom view for each of the items which identified which 'part' of the string was being entered and displayed that part in the dropdown item.

For my solution, I then hide the autocompletetextview, but you could also just call setText to overwrite the default behavior.